# "Package None is not a value" when initializing a scala Option

Tags: scala

The following code is generating the error from the question title:

```
override val inCentroidsDf: Option[DataFrame] = None
```

And here's the punch line:

```
Error:(15, 51) package None is not a value
  override val inCentroidsDf: Option[DataFrame] = None
```

So.. is this really incorrect / what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another transient Intellij bug: the code compiles from the command line.  I should remember to try anything strange out from our trusty

```
mvn clean package
```

After that completed (successfully) I then recompiled yet again on intellij: but still same (spurious) compilation error.   Next step - `Build | Rebuild Project`. Let's see what that says..

*Ya ..*  full `Rebuild project` cleaned up whatever was confused inside the Intellij caches..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some package named `None` in scope? That's quite a strange name for a package, but it's the only explanation I know of for that error. I would recommend renaming that package.

What happens if you do:

```
override val inCentroidsDf: Option[DataFrame] = scala.None
```

Comment: No i looked for that ;)   This is looking like an intellij bug:  I am verifying via `mvn package` command line now..

Comment: Seems reasonable - if building from the command line doesn't have the same issue, it definitely could be an IDE bug.